# Read-Write data from /dev/test file in android root file system in rooted device from android app

Tags: java, android, linux, filesystems

I am trying to read-write data from /dev/test node in android file system.
I tried

```
mount -o rw remount /dev && touch /dev/test
```

from shell and it worked, but when I try to use

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("su");
proc = rt.exec("mount -o rw remount /dev && touch /dev/test");
```

There is no file called test under /dev/

Comment: /dev is not a location for ordinary files.  Creating one there with `touch` is a mistake.  Use `mknod`, but don't expect the result to behave like an ordinary file.  What are you actually trying to **accomplish**?

Comment: I am creating a system service that will be writing into the file and polled by the device driver.

Comment: In addition to using the wrong operation for the task (as already mentioned, you must use `mknod` with the appropriate major and minor numbers and device type rather than `touch`), you aren't running it as the superuser.  Each call to exec() is independent - your invocation of su does nothing but exit, then you try to run other commands as your app's user, not as root.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the info, but Android kernel does not have mknod, :(     Any other solution? Basically I am creating an app that will RW some data into this /dev node and the driver will be polling this node for data.

Comment: You are mistaken.  The Kernel most definitely has mknod.  Additionally, android's toolbox shell environment normally provides a tool to invoke it - if that is missing on your system you will probably have to provide you own copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exec it using this method:

```
private boolean performScript(String script) {
        script = "mount -o rw remount /dev && touch /dev/test";
        try {
            // Executes the command.
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(script + "\n");
            os.flush();
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();

//                // Reads stdout.
//                // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using process.getOutputStream().
//                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
//                int read;
//                final char[] buffer = new char[4096];
//                while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
//                    stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, read);
//                    txtInfo.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
//                }
//                reader.close();

            // Waits for the command to finish.
            process.waitFor();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the trick here is to run the script being a superuser.

Comment: Did it ask you for SU rights? And did you allow it?

Comment: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); will grant su access

Comment: Tried reading the stout by    InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   String line;

   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, line);
   }

Comment: And what does it say? Did you try my method with no any changes/modifying?

Comment: Because I opened the /dev/test file and saw nothing in it

Comment: Im afraid thats cuz the script is finished. I guess that atm script runs you gonna see mounted point but after that mounted point dies with script togther. Try to `l` inside `/dev` in script to see if it really mounts the point.